# Client side paging for Asp.Net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

this is my MVC action that returns a list of posts:

```
 public ActionResult Posts()
        {
            var blogPost = _blogRepository.GetAllPost();
            var blogPostViewModel = blogPost.ConvertToPostViewModelList();
            return View("Posts", blogPostViewModel);
        }
```

and also this is my View

```
@model IEnumerable<Blog.Web.UI.ViewModels.PostViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div>
            <h3>
                @Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Post", "Blog", new { postId = item.Id, postSlug = item.UrlSlug }, null)
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Category: </span>@item.Category.Name
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Tag: </span>@item.Tag.Name
        </div>
        <div>
            @item.CreationDate.ToLongDateString()
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.DisplayTextFor(p => item.Body)
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

I want to implement a Client Side paging for this page that render all of the post by date , is it possible ?? or I should change my code to make it server side ??

Comment: you can use ajax to do this :)

Comment: thanks! but how ?? do you know a good example?

Comment: sorry, I don't have example for you. you can use ajax to load set of items for 1 page. when click next/prev, you reload new set and re-render html. I think jQuery.html() and jQuery.ajax() will be helpful in this case

Answer (score 0):

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/13/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx

It's old but relevant and should help you achieve what your looking for.